# Firebase: How are we supposed to handle occasional deployment error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

We have a web app written in Vue + Firebase. When we deploy functions, it occasionally fails with error like this.

```
functions[api(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "ee61c49673c5d4aa8d5b0deb6eee0b19bf866203e030204be0aefe8dca34355f", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "HIT", "hash": "ee61c49673c5d4aa8d5b0deb6eee0b19bf866203e030204be0aefe8dca34355f", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}
```

When we are deploying manually, we just redeploy to work around.

We want to move to automated deployment, but I am wondering if we should just re-deploy it in the script. We'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to figure out for yourself what you want to do if the Firebase CLI fails.  That might involve writing a loop to keep deploying until it completes.  I wouldn't loop infinitely, since it might require manual attention.  But you will have to work it out in any event.  There is no "guided path" provided by Firebase for your situation.